# FileNotFoundException in Android studio access denied using cordova project

Tags: java, exception, cordova, android-studio

IDE: android studio
Project : Cordova
when i am going to run my android studio application using cordova project
i am having a problem

```
Error:Android Packager: [android1] java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\first Cordova app\myFirstCordovaMobileApp\platforms\android\gen (Access is denied)
```

what's wrong with the project?? do i need to do some more work?

Answer (score 0):

when I see "access denied", I think of permission so I would start my IDE as administrator (right click->run as Administrator) and run my project again